# IIS 7 Cannot Access Website

Tags: domain-name-system, iis-7, website

We can access our website from other systems, but when logged into the local machine where the site is hosted it does not resolve to the site... for example: http://mysite.com/folder/page.aspx   gets a 404.... from the local machine we also cannot ping mysite.com ... What are some common things to check to troubleshoot this issue? I'm new to IIS 7 so sorry for the vague question.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a DNS issue. Setup an additional binding to port 80 with a blank host name. Then access the site via http://localhost/ or http://127.0.0.1 - you should then see it. Then it's a case of diagnosing the DNS issue.

One solution would be to 'hardcode' it in the hosts file (C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\Etc\hosts) as 127.0.0.1 mysite.com

Answer (score 0):

In 2003 R2 and up, there is a security thing preventing you from using a alias to reach the localhost.

You can either add an OptionalName using this command (fill in ALIAS):

```
netdom computername ALIAS /add
```

Or just turn off the security check altogether (if you run the first command, it will create a OptionalName key in this same location):

1. Locate and click the following key in the registry:
   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanServer\Parameters
2. On the Edit menu, click Add Value, and then add the following registry value:
   Value name: DisableStrictNameChecking
   Data type: REG_DWORD
   Radix: Decimal
   Value: 1

Answer (score 0):

Reviewing the W3SVC logs is *a common thing to check to troubleshoot this issue*.

See here for more info on IIS logging:

http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/579/advanced-logging-for-iis-70---custom-logging/

Specifically in your case, confirming the substatus code for the 404 may prove useful.  Use this article to decipher these codes in IIS7:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/943891